# 3rd Party files via Github in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, github, repository

I know there is a way to link Github and Xcode together to PUSH your project to Git but I have not heard of a way where you can set it up to have it where Git projects are within your existing project.

For example, ShareKit: https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit...

Is there a way so that I can have all the ShareKit files from a particular branch in that repo in my project so that whenever I build my project, it will check to see whether or not I have the latest version of the files from Github and if not, it will automatically download it and use it in my project?

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up as normal, File -> Source Control -> Pull or Merge (depending on what you want)

Comment: And this will guarantee that whenever I build my project, it will have the latest code from the repo?

Comment: Ah, not every time you build (you need to do it manually, but really it is not that big of a hassle), if you want to force an update every time you are going to have to add it to your "pre-actions" section in your edit schemes area as a script (with the appropriate git command)